# How to align the below code

Tags: css, html

How to get the menu bar right below the Dial food caption and remove the underline shown in the below code:

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1 style="color: #CC6600; height: 100px; width: auto;">
            Dial food</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="Menu" style="background-color: #330000; font-size: 20px; height: 25px; width:auto;
        word-spacing: 24px; position:absolute">
        <a href="">About </a>
        <a href="">Restaurants </a>
        <a href="">Contact </a>
        <a href="">Support</a> 
    </div>
</body>
```

can you please help me in getting this alignment and link text only get aligned?

Comment: Please mark an answer as accepted if it answered your question or give feed back if it didn't.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change the `<h1>` height to 15px to bring the menu bar up. (or a value to your liking)

```
<h1 style="color: #CC6600; height: 15px; width: auto;">
```

And use the following CSS to remove the underline.

```
#Menu a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6bxVr/

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**
  
            Dial food

```
   <ul>
        <li>  <a href="">About </a> </li>
         <li><a href="">Restaurants </a></li>
         <li><a href="">Contact </a></li>
         <li><a href="">Support</a> </li>
    </ul>
```

**CSS**

```
    .header
    {
    color: #CC6600; 
        height:20px;
        width: auto;    
        margin:10px;
    }


    ul
    {
        list-style:none;
    }
    ul li
    {
        float:left;
        padding:10px;
        background-color: #330000; 
        word-spacing: 24px;
        font-size: 20px;
        height: 25px;
        width:auto;


    }
    li a
    {


  text-decoration:none;
}
```

**Fiddle** [Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/nyf2G/8/)

[Update fiddle of Yours](http://jsfiddle.net/2Qu2h/7/)

Hope this helps

happy coding..!!